# Chrome slow rendering ajax loaded tables

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, primefaces

I have a XHTML/Java/Primefaces project with sortable/paginated DataTables (where you can filter by text, sort or show 10/50/100 rows), and one of them (strangely not the other tables) is really slow in loading the contents when there are 100 rows shown, but this error happens only in google Chrome, in Safari/Firefox it works perfectly (Chrome is about 10x slower than the others). When monitoring the Performance Inspector, it gets locked in rendering out the table.

I tried some fixes as suggested by others with turning on hardware rendering via `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` and `table-layout:fixed;` but none of them worked.

I believe it is somewhat a chrome bug, but any suggestion how to fix it?

Versions:
Google Chrome: Version 68.0.3440.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Primefaces: version 6.2

Comment: Might be best to see if you can reproduce it with an MVCE using the PrimeFaces Test project: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test   If you can reproduce it I suggest reporting it to the PF team.

Comment: Ant provide version info

Comment: Both PF an Chrome

Comment: And please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive and http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ (did not downvote... yet), but we are trying to  HELP YOU, please help us in that regard

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I'll look into it in more detail, hope we can find the solution. I update the post with the version numbers, sorry I missed it.

Comment: Creating a [mcve] and comparing with the others is the most important thing to do

Answer (score 0):

We found out with my colleagues that the problem are the editable rows, probably because there are many hidden fields. Strange it gets rendered very quickly in Firefox/Safari.

Thank you for the infos, much appreciated, and sorry for the posting mistakes.

Comment: Is this in PF 6.2? Tried 6.1? Just to see if it is related ro the major upgrade of jquery in PrimeFaces 6.2

Comment: Yes, PrimeFaces 6.2